# arithmetic calculation with time_format() conversion and timediff() are showing different results, why?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

This shall be my virgin question to the community. I am looking to understand why is it, these 2 code which should be returning the same output, are producing different answers. The difference between these 2 codes is in the 5th line. The first code uses timediff() while the second does not.

code 1,

```
with session_duration as (
select    
    a.user_id,
    a.timestamp as date,
    min(timediff(b.timestamp, a.timestamp)) as duration
from
    web_log a join web_log b
    on a.user_id = b.user_id
where 
    a.action = 'page_load' and
    b.action = 'page_exit' and
    b.timestamp > a.timestamp
group by user_id, date
)

select 
    user_id,
    time_format(avg(duration), '%H:%i:%s') as avg_duration
from session_duration
group by user_id
order by avg_duration
```

code 2,

```
with session_duration as (
select    
    a.user_id,
    a.timestamp as date,
    min(b.timestamp - a.timestamp) as duration
from
    web_log a join web_log b
    on a.user_id = b.user_id
where 
    a.action = 'page_load' and
    b.action = 'page_exit' and
    b.timestamp > a.timestamp
group by user_id, date
)

select 
    user_id,
    time_format(avg(duration), '%H:%i:%s') as avg_duration
from session_duration
group by user_id
order by avg_duration
;
```

Shouldn't the answer between these 2 be the same? There seem to be a 20 minutes gap between the 2 and i'm unsure which of the 2 is displaying the right answer. Any proper explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want to subtract two timestamps, use the function designed for that.  `-` turns the values into numbers and doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Alright, so it doesn't work like excel in which you can directly conduct arithmetic on the date, got it. Thanks!